# Input Variables with Inconsistent Number of Samples

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

```
combine_data = pd.read_csv('combine_data.csv')
combine_data
```

```
combine_data = combine_data.drop(columns=['Ht','Wt','Player','Pos','Year','Pfr_ID', 'AV', 'Team','Round'])
combine_data = combine_data.dropna(subset=['Forty','Vertical','BenchReps','BroadJump','Cone','Shuttle','Pick'])
```

```
combine_data_X = combine_data.drop(columns=['Pick'])
combine_data_X
```

```
X = combine_data_X
y = combine_data['Pick']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size =0.2)
```

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

```
predictions = model.predict([[4.2,40,40,120,4.5,2.3]])
predictions
```

```
score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
score
```

I have tried reshaping the X and y variables but I get the same error.

```
ValueError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-a530c0d4a08a> in <module>
     29 predictions
     30 
---> 31 score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
     32 score
```

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [365, 1]
```

How would I fix this error? I am thinking it is dimension size of the testing set but I am not sure

Comment: `y_test` should of same size as of `predictions` .

Comment: ok thank you, I figured out the issue instead of testing the accuracy of the model on actual data I was supposed to predict on the testing data set. Thank you for your help